# How to bake a normal map using a mix shader

Tags: texturing, materials, texture-baking, normal-map

I have the nodes shown below, but if I just put on an image and try to bake a normal map, it comes out wrong. Is there a proper way to handle baking normals in this scenario? As there are two materials being mixed into one output im assuming that I did it wrong.

[image: Shaders]

Comment: Could you clarify a little? What exactly is wrong with the baked map?

Comment: The one I made was just plain blue

Comment: Is your model UV unwrapped?

Comment: @SamuelSullins Yes, but is there a specific margin you'd recommend?

Comment: Just needs a tiny margin. Could you add a picture with your bake settings? And do you have an image texture node in your material for the bake to target? (I assume you do, just making sure)